# Is there a reason for installing the NPM module locally?

Tags: node.js, npm

I was looking at my package.json for a project I've been working on for the past year and I saw that npm itself was in that json file.

I want to keep the number of packages to a minimum, but there is a too much code to trace through line by line and see if it is ever used.

Im leaning towards removing it, but I want to make sure that removing it wont break the project.

Can you think of a valid local use of npm?

Comment: It makes no sense at all to have npm as a dependency in a file that has the prerequisite for having npm installed.

Comment: Makes sense if NPM is used programmatically.

Comment: can NPM be used programmatically?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. If the project uses it, it makes sense to provide specific NPM version as a dependency to avoid compatibility issues with global NPM. This is an edge case but it exists.